# Can't match ssh key for git. Makes local fingerprint instead?

Tags: linux, windows, git, ssh

My target is to set up git on my Linux server box so I can commit/push through a batch file from my windows machine.
I was hoping for something similar to how I did it with svn in the past, such that I could create a user that had certain read/write privileges. I am more than happy for it to be ssh key dependant.
Thus far every time I try to put an ssh key on my computer and on the server, it just ignores it and makes its own:

```
The authenticity of host 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

And this means I have to insert a password every time so my batch file solution won't work.

I placed the key on my windows machine both in "C:/Users/Ryan/.ssh/" and "C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/.ssh/" in the msysgit installation directory. I also installed it onto my server to the suggested git user. I did the basic installation following the [git documentation](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server):
 - Generated myself an SSH key using puttygen.
 - Copied it to my server and cat'd it to authorized_keys in /home/git/.ssh/
 - Init'd bare git repository etc.

I can push/pull but I have to use the RSA fingerprint and use the git account password to log in rather than using an ssh key.

Am I doing something wrong is it actually supposed to work like this?

I haven't fully read into making a git daemon instead, perhaps that is what I am after?

Comment: Check if you have a known_hosts file created in your .ssh/. Also make sure the private key is named id_rsa and not something like larry or larry_rsa etc.

Comment: Yea saw known_hosts in that folder quite a few times. I wanted to try and get it working with the ssh key, so I kept deleting it and retrying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are starting a DOS session with [`git-cmd.bat`](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/git-cmd.bat) from your msysgit distribution: that will set the `HOME` environment variable properly (usually  `%USERPROFILE%`).

The public (`id_rsa.pub`) and private (`id_rsa`) keys need to be in `%HOME%\.ssh`.

The message `The authenticity of host` should only occurs one, at the first ssh connection. Once it is done, don't delete the `%HOME%\.ssh\known_hosts` file it has created.

Comment: the issue is, I don't seem to require a key at all to be able to push to my repository. It simply ensures that I log in as the user and just pushes to it. Are you saying if I get the id_rsa and id_rsa.pub in the correct places that I shouldn't have to log in as the "git" user anymore?

Comment: @Larry if your `git remote -v` returns a ssh url, then you don't login. If it is an https url... then those ssh keys would not be used. At all. What is the output of `git remote -v`?

Comment: yea as it turns out I think the ssh ID's were not lining up. So I placed both files in my home directory with the correct naming convention and whala, worked like a charm! Turns out I didn't realise what the difference between the generated files was...